# Continuous order IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I need help with this IMPORTRANGE formula, since I have report for a month:

```
=ImportRange("1cMXye4cfqaUz8mMghe43_lNJZAYuY-GDTCNIOaT5b84","Invoice-Schedule!B34:F34")
```

This is only for one day, and I have 100 other rows with different invoice files  for the same day. When I want to copy and past for the next days this code the range should automatically change like this: `"Invoice-Schedule!B35:F35"`, "`Invoice-Schedule!B36:F36`" but it is not changing automatically. I can't change it manually because I have too much data.

Is there any other formula that I can add to implement it?

Comment: There's any number of ways to programmatically build the string that you want, such that the formula that creates the string can be used with autofill / drag-down / drag-across. Try using `ROW`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to change the code to one row only.

The way to do it is:

1. Create a named range called: "RowToGet".
2. Change the second argument to this: `"Invoice-Schedule!B" & RowToGet & ":F" & RowToGet`

Then if you wanted to change the formula's output 100 times, do it for each of your 100 `importrange` formulas. Then changing a value in the range "RowToGet" you'll change all 100 formulas.